# SaaS multi_tenant questions

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, multi-tenant, saas

I am currently working on a multi tenant system for SaaS, but due to my lack of experience before, I have some doubts about having more tenants.

1. Currently, a single database is used to distinguish the data of each tenant based on their ID,
   Nowadays, with a large amount of data, efficiency is very low. We have considered having one library for each tenant, but the product is not mature enough and we often modify data tables, which undoubtedly increases the workload.
2. The database uses MySQL, and now tenants have different queries for data, covering almost all fields. How to optimize or implement it through other technical solutions.
3. In terms of field management, different tenants have different needs and propose customization at the field level. Customization should be implemented for whether each unit is enabled, field aliases, field permissions, list display, import and export.
   I hope you can provide some experience or insights. If there are any cases, it would be great. Thank you

We have considered having one library for each tenant, but the product is not mature enough and we often modify data tables, which undoubtedly increases the workload.

Comment: I am doing the same in one of my personal project and what I am doing is saparating each tenant in different schema. Yo can handle the migration of every schema using flyway or liquibase and select the schema in runtime based, for example, in a value coming from the request. 

I am saving the schema name in the JWT token, so every time a request is made, Im setting the schema name in the ThreadLocal. I am using this approach: https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/31/how-to-integrate-hibernates-multitenant-feature-with-spring-data-jpa-in-a-spring-boot-application

Comment: @Merch0 in mysql schema and database are synonyms - is your project mysql based or sql-server perhaps?

Comment: It is postgres. But you coudl follow the same approach using multiple datasource for the different databases.